# Opening local file from php script in browser tab

Tags: php

I am creating and writing to html file in php file. After I have written the information in the html I want to open the html in a browser tab.The html is saved into directory on my filesystem and I know the path. I can open the html in the browser by typing in "file:///C:/Apache24/htdocs/test.html" and i see the html successfully , but how can I do this with php?

Comment: Open the URL `http://localhost/test.html`

Comment: Thanks that is a great idea, it will solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things to start running PHP files in the browser

1. Install Xampp on your computer and run apache from its control panel

> Download link : https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
> Xampp Control panel: [image]
> 2. Save your PHP files in htdocs folder in your xampp folder (file extension should be .php)

now you can go to your browser and run http://localhost/test.php to see the output of your code.